# Transact SQL - How to perform additional operation on a result set

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a simple query:

```
select id, count(*) n
from mytable
group by id
```

Is it possible to include also the sum(n) in the same query? So the result would look something like this:

```
id   n
---- -----------
1    12
2    1
3    14
4    1
5    2
6    6

Sum=36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **[common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)** to do this:

```
--
; WITH cte as (SELECT id
               ,count(*) n
               FROM mytable
               GROUP BY id)
SELECT id, n FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sum', SUM(n) from cte
```

---

You can also use **[ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28SQL.90%29.aspx)**: (this may not be exactly correct syntax)

```
SELECT id
      ,count(*) n
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: WITH ROLLUP - I knew I saw it somewhere :) Thanks!